# can not Hyperlink a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have a url Which i want to hyperlink on my website  but that url is not working after giving hyperlink or copy-pasting in the web address bar or refreshing the page, that url is only working from the original website. . . . If Open the link from original  website its opening but Source code is invisible . . . .please help me

URL is 
      http://jntuconnect.net/results/results/zMO9-z4RtsGFvQq5BcFyav1G9WYwHAkyfMoH49pbaATJCr3zhnoPJnBVYvTw_4fBxyMLLmVLHauTIwzoqJSTHA,,

Please help  me in hyper linking it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, when you copy and paste the link and try to code it on your website it doesn't work? You get directed to a different location on click?

Comment: I would guess that the site is loading the content dynamically.  It probably is checking a cookie for a type of authentication.

Comment: Are you trying to hotlink a site which is not your?

Comment: yah i want to link some urls in my website, but those links or not even working if we copy & paste it in a new browser or tab

Comment: Ya, of course, thats why temporary tokens have been created to not let other people steal the work of others...

Comment: i would agree with Javalsu's comment - if you go to http://jntuconnect.net  or http://jntuconnect.net/results and click on one of the links you'll see that it asks for a hall ticket #; whatever that is - so in a nutshell, what you want to do is probably not possible

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link to a results page that is dynamically generated and behind a CAPCHA.

My guess would be that the long string of hash at the end of the URL is an encoded string that contains a time stamp or some other expiring method. Also since the page you want is behind a CAPCHA check that long hash at the end of the URL probably also encodes some sort of "success"  message that says you filled out the CAPCHA. It wont be possible to link directly to the "results" page because it doesn't exist until some query parameters generate it.

A better option would be to see if they "iBongo" offers an API you can query. iBongo seems to be the company that is powering http://jntuconnect.net.